# PHP - Large Integer mod calculation

Tags: php, integer, math, modulo

I need to calculate modulus with large number like :

```
<?php

    $largenum = 95635000009453274121700;

    echo $largenum % 97;

?>
```

It's not working... because $largenum is too big for an int in PHP.

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use **[`bcmod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php)** from **[BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)**:

```
$largenum = '95635000009453274121700';
echo bcmod($largenum, '97');
```

Note, that `$largenum` is passed as a string, not converted to int.